# Exceptions before deploying to production

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, monitoring

Recently had an interview and they asked me the question. 
How to monitor exceptions before deploying to prod? It was asked in context of spring-boot and logs. It seems they were unhappy I answered that I will go to logs and look through them.

What are the modern tools to do this?

Comment: Not sure what the context is, but one can implement an exception listener and ... email the developers when an exception occurs?

Comment: It depend  to the context: 1- Transport the content of exception to the front , 2- Return the exception as a personal object via Http status with RestControllerAdvice, 3- you can implement a listener to notify users via email, 4- you can use netflix hystrix in your spring boot app then users can check the failed request, 5- Elastic Stack